# Struggling to verify a JWT token in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0, jose

Please bear with me as I'm new to JWT and find it terribly confusing.

I have an Auth0-provided JWT which I need to verify. I'm using [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose). Here's what I have:

```
const {payload, protectedHeader} = await jose.jwtVerify(
    token,
    secret,
    {algorithms: ['RS256']}
);
```

...where `token` is the JWT passed from my front-end to my back-end, and `secret` is my application secret (Auth0 > Applications > Settings.)

When run, this yields:

> Key for the RS256 algorithm must be of type CryptoKey.

I read on Auth0 somewhere that RS256 JWTs must be verified with a private signing key. Not really knowing what this means, and because Auth0 also says that HS256 can be verified with the **secret**, I changed my signing algorithm to HS256. When I run the above, I then get:

> "alg" (Algorithm) Header Parameter value not allowed

Any help here is hugely appreciated. I'm going round in circles.

Comment: *I changed my signing algorithm to HS256* - if you receive a JWT, it's not your choice which algorithm is used. The JWT was signed using a certain algorithm, e.g. HS256, RS256). You can inspect your token on https://jwt.io and see what algorithm is set in the header, eg. "alg" = "RS256". If it's RS256, you need to get a public key (not a private key) to verify the signature. RS256 is the short name for RSA-SHA256 and always uses a key-pair, a private key for signing and a public key for verification. Often these public keys are published online as a JWKS (JSON Web Key Set).

Comment: It's my choice in the sense that I control my Auth0 account, and within my application I can choose the signing algorithm - RS256 or HS256. Thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify the JWT a token signing public key is needed. Usually code like this is used, to download it from the authorization server's JWKS endpoint.

```js
import {createRemoteJWKSet, jwtVerify, JWTPayload} from 'jose';

const jwksUri = 'https://login.example.com/jwks';
const jwks = createRemoteJWKSet(new URI(jwksUri));

async function validateJWT(accessToken: string): Promise<JwtPayload> {

  const options = {
    algorithms: ['RS256'],
    issuer: 'myissuer',
    audience: 'myaudience'
  };

  const result = await jwtVerify(accessToken, jwks, options);
  return result.payload
}
```

Note that you must use an asymmetric signing algorithm. This enables any API or client to validate JWTs (with the public key), while only the authorization server can issue them (with the private key). More info in [my blog post](https://authguidance.com/jwt-access-token-validation/).

**WORKING CODE**

You can run [this web and API example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts) if you follow the [README instructions](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1) and maybe compare the code against your own.

Comment: THANK YOU! I really appreciate your reply. I've been banging my head against this for a day, just going round and round in the docs. Some questions/points: 1. `new URI()` throws an error; I had to use `new URL` instead. 2. `JWTPayload` is apparently not a valid export. 3. Where you have `accessToken`, that means the JWT itself, right? i.e. the thing I received after resolving the user's access token (post-login) via the Auth0 API. 4. How would I also grab the JWT's payload? I tried Jose's `decodeJwt()`, but that gives me the same output as `jwtVerify()`.

Comment: Scratch point 4 re: decoding - I was mistaken.

Comment: I added a link to some working code you can run. Maybe compare that to your own code and that will help you to get integrated.